# How to assign a value to a static field dynamically create objects?

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create an object using reflection class `PropertyCondition(in assembly UIAutomationClient.dll)`. In order to obtain the desired class constructor, I use the following code:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().First(x => x.FullName.Contains("AutomationClient"));

var propertyConditionType = assembly.DefinedTypes.First(x => x.Name == "PropertyCondition");
var automationElementType = assembly.DefinedTypes.First(x => x.Name == "AutomationElement");

var automationIdPropertyType = automationElementType.GetField("AutomationIdProperty").FieldType;
var constructor = propertyConditionType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { automationIdPropertyType, typeof(object) });
```

But how do I pass in constructor `AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step you are missing is a simple `FieldInfo.GetValue` call, to get the value you have to pass into the constructor. I restructured your code:

```
var automationIdPropertyField = automationElementType.GetField("AutomationIdProperty");

var automationIdPropertyType = automationIdPropertyField.FieldType;
var automationIdPropertyValue = automationIdPropertyField.GetValue(null);

var constructor = propertyConditionType.GetConstructor(new[] { automationIdPropertyType, typeof(object) });

var obj = constructor.Invoke(new[] {automationIdPropertyValue, ...});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that [`automationId` is a string property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.automationid(v=vs.110).aspx). And what you need is find `constructor` which accepts `strings`:

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = propertyConditionType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { automationId });
```

Or you can use [Activator.CreateInstance Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx):

> CreateInstance(AppDomain, String, String, Boolean, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo, Object[])
>
> Creates an instance of the type whose name is specified in the
>   specified remote domain, using the named assembly and the constructor
>   that best matches the specified parameters.

Comment: I opened the assembly in a decompiler and i think there is no constructor that takes a string.

Comment: No,PropertyCondition class has next constructors:
        public PropertyCondition(AutomationProperty property, object value);

        public PropertyCondition(AutomationProperty property, object value, PropertyConditionFlags flags);

Comment: That way may be you should pass as parameter whole  `Automation Element` instead its `id`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752331(v=vs.110).aspx